# Polyamide roller nap

Tags: painting

Is there any advantage in a polyamide vs polyester roller nap? I'm generally aware of the differences between polyamide and polyester: the former is more elastic and retains more water; it feels softer in hand. Is a polyamide roller just a marketing gimmick (to justify a higher price) or is there some concrete advantage in using a polyamide roller nap?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently they hold most paint for a given nap size. I came to this conclusion after looking at Purdy Colossus. The downside seems to be that polyamide cannot quite be made lint free (even by Purdy). The ones I purchased (not by Purdy as it was not available locally) kept shedding fibers which was annoying.

Comment: TL;DR: If it says Purdy, carry on. If not throw it away. *nap-smap*